# Versions.app: How to select Kaleidoscope.app as diff tool?

Tags: versions

## Setup

- OS X 10.8.2
- Versions 1.1.11
- Kaleidoscope 2.0.0

---

## Problem

I am a registered user (DirectSales, not AppStore) of both [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) and [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) (both from [BlackPixel](http://blackpixel.com/)). The latest versions of both apps are installed on on my system.

I would like to configure Versions.app to use Kaleidoscope.app as its diff tool.

However, when I go to

```
Versions.app > Preferences > File Comparison
```

I see Kaleidoscope grayed out with a generic icon (see screencap below). Since both apps are from the same developer, I think I must be missing something obvious, or there may be a problem with my system.

So: How to select Kaleidoscope.app as the diff tool in Versions.app?

[image]

Comment: Big fan of fluid :) (just sayin')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- From the Kaleidoscope app go to Kaleidoscope menu > Integration...

[image: command line tool ksdiff]
Install the ksdiff tool

- Quit and relaunch Versions and Kaleidoscope should be selectable.

If that doesn't work, check with Black Pixel's [amazing support team](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/support) after being sure you have [build 104 of Kaleidoscope 2.0](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/releasenotes)